# Parsing JSon data in AngularJS from $http call

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

I'm very new to both web development and AngularJS. I am trying to write a web page that will automatically update its info based on JSon files sitting on my server. I can get the json data but I can't seem to parse the data coming in. I validated the json data just to make sure I was writing it correctly, but whenever I display it on the site is just displays as a single string. I am not able to access the individual members. My factory and controller are below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
var MyController = function($scope, $log, MyFactory) {
    $scope.notes =[];

function init() {
    MyFactory.getNotes()
        .success(function(notes){
            $scope.notes = JSON.parse(notes);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status);
            });
}

    init();

angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
};
```

And the factory:

```
    var MyFactory = function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getNotes = function() {
        return $http.get('/ci/data.json');
    };
return factory;
};

angular.module('MyApp').factory('MyFactory', 
                                    MyFactory);
```

I admit the code and question is crude but I've just started. Any additional help on architecture and style would be appreciated as well! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of the json response?

Comment: For example, [{"name":"matt","age":32},{"name":"dave","age":29}]. It would print it out just like that. If I sent that to the $scope then tried accessing say, name, it would work. It will only print out the entire string.

Comment: Do you have quotes around the whole thing in the data.json file? That would make the whole thing just one json string I guess.

Comment: Also I think Angular should be parsing the json itself if it detects the response is json data, so you wouldn't need to do the manual JSON.parse. A quick way to see what's going in would be to try console.log(notes) in your success function and see what actually gets passed (a string or an object)

Comment: Nope. I just have it around the methods and variables

Comment: I took the JSON.parse() out and out in the console.log(notes) as you said and in the log it's passing it as an object which just confuses me more. notes is loaded in the $scope but if in one of the views I try an ng-repeat and {{ notes.name }} it returns nothing.

Comment: The view issue sounds like a different question, would need to see the HTML to see if there's a problem there. What does the object look like that gets passed to success? If it's a straightforward array then fine, otherwise if notes is an object you might need to access the array differently, e.g. notes.data or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't need to parse the response as json. If the sourcefile is giving you valid json, angular knows its json.
2. In your controller, try to `console.log($scope.notes)`. If using google chrome, you get the `json` results pretty printed in the console you know your `factory` is working.
3. Use an angular `forEach` to iterate through the result to do something with it.

   ```
   angular.forEach($scope.notes, function(note) {
       console.log(note);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angular.fromJson(jsondata)` to parse http result.
Previously i was getting invalid json data from http response, some `"\` characters were there in the json data so i parsed using this and it worked for me, it removed all those invalid characters from my json data.

Answer (score 0):

**No Need to parse..
just use your $scope.notes in you loop**

```
<div ng-repeat="note as notes">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>{{age}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who may still need this, Suresh's answer is in the right direction but that code was quite wrong (at least for Angular 1)

So whilst trying to parse data such as:

```
{"1":{"id":"1","owner":"1","name":"Server","description":"This is my test server.","version":"1.11","type":"0","ip":"test.com","port":"25565"},"2":{"id":"2","owner":"1","name":"Test Server","description":"This is my test server.","version":"1.0","type":"2","ip":"test.com","port":"25565"}
```

I used the following GET request:

```
.controller('serversController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("/dashboard/api/?action=getServers&key=")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.servers = response.data;
  });
});
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="server in servers">
    <p>{{server.id}}</p>
    <p>{{server.name}}</p>
    <p>{{server.version}}</p>
</div>
```